# How to calculate or estimate an energy deposition inside $\rm BeO$?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, x-rays, particle-detectors

I wonder how one could or would calculate the energy deposition inside e.g. $\rm BeO$. To simplify the radiation source shall be a photon with 160 keV and $\rm BeO$ is 0.5 mm thick and 1 mm² wide.

Comment: Start with https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/intro.html

Comment: Thanks, just to know where this is going I would use eq. 1 on https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/chap2.html then ultimately?